# How to route GET and POST for same pattern in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Does anyone know of any way in Laravel 4 which combines these 2 lines into one?

```php
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
```

So instead of having to write both you only have to write one since their both using the 'same' method but also the URL remains as `site.com/login` instead of a redirect to `site.com/auth/login`?

I'm curious since I remember CI has something like that where the URL remains the same and the controller is never shown:

```php
$route['(method1|method2)'] = 'controller/$1';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Route::controller('login','AuthController');
```

Then in your `AuthController class` implement these methods:

```
public function getIndex();
public function postIndex();
```

It should work ;)

Comment: Note from the future: [implicit controllers are deprecated in Laravel 5.2 and will be removed in the future](http://benjaminkohl.com/post/implicit-controller-routing-is-deprecated-in-laravel-5-2).

Answer (score 89):

The docs say...

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

source:  http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Comment: This answer is more precise.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this getting so many upvotes? Yes it explains how you use both GET and POST but says nothing about how to call the different methods depending on the request type.

Answer (score 55):

See the below code.

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'login', 'AuthController@login');
```

Comment: The only answer to properly answer the question.

Answer (score 39):

You can combine all HTTP verbs for a route using:

```php
Route::any('login', 'AuthController@login');
```

This will match both `GET` and `POST` HTTP verbs. And it will also match for `PUT`, `PATCH` & `DELETE`.

Comment: How would you check if the verb is a `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: You can always use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`, but I will not recommend to mix in one action two logic... the idea with controller is to **separate the logic** in conjunction with Post-Redirect-Get pattern. Take 2 or 3 mins to read this specific thread: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1517.

Comment: @enchance , you can check is it `GET` or `POST` with:

`if (Request::isMethod('post'))`
`{`
`//...`
`}`

Answer (score 22):

```
Route::any('login', 'AuthController@login');
```

and in controller:

```
if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{
// ... this is POST method
}
if (Request::isMethod('get'))
{
// ... this is GET method
}
...
```

Comment: This is a better answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

As per the latest docs, it should be

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/routing

Comment: How is this any different from the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23235478) made 5 years prior?

Answer (score 6):

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT'), "/", array(
    'uses' => 'Controller@index',
    'as' => 'index'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Routes

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'/login', 'AuthController@getLogin');
```

In Controller

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    if($input){
     //Do with your post parameters
    }
    return view('login');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use match to handle both methods

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'], 'users', UserController@store);
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from the existing ones?

Comment: @gre_gor One thing that tripped me up was that the controller is no longer passed as a string, rather as the object itself. I tried old code and it didn't work in Laravel 10 as a string.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.1 this can be achieved by Implicit Controllers.
see what I found from the laravel documentation

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

Next, just add methods to your controller. The method names should begin with the HTTP verb they respond to followed by the title case version of the URI:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Responds to requests to GET /users
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Responds to requests to GET /users/show/1
     */
    public function getShow($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Responds to requests to GET /users/admin-profile
     */
    public function getAdminProfile()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Responds to requests to POST /users/profile
     */
    public function postProfile()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Right, I'm answering using my mobile, and so I haven't tested this (if I remember correctly, it isn't in the documentation either). Here goes:

```
Route::match('(GET|POST)', 'login',
    'AuthController@login'
);
```

That should do the trick. If it doesn't, then Taylor had it removed from the core; which would then mean that nobody was using it.