# Check if request is GET or POST

Tags: php, post, get, laravel-4

In my controller/action:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(Auth::attempt(Input::get('data')))
    {
        return Redirect::intended();
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flash('error_message','');
    }
}
```

Is there a method in `Laravel` to check if the request is `POST` or `GET`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've solve my problem like below in laravel version: 7+

**In routes/web.php:**

```
Route::post('url', YourController@yourMethod);
```

**In app/Http/Controllers:**

```
public function yourMethod(Request $request) {
    switch ($request->method()) {
        case 'POST':
            // do anything in 'post request';
            break;

        case 'GET':
            // do anything in 'get request';
            break;

        default:
            // invalid request
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 181):

According to [Laravels docs](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information), there's a Request method to check it, so you could just do:

```
$method = Request::method();
```

or

```
if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{
// 
}
```

Answer (score 84):

The solutions above are outdated.

As per [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#basic-request-information):

```
$method = $request->method();

if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    //
}
```

Comment: `Undefined variable: request`

Comment: This works where you are passing the request to a function e.g 
`function myFunction (Request $request, $otherParams) {
    if($request->method == 'get') {}
}`

Comment: Or just use `request()->isMethod('post')` anywhere cause the function `request()` is registered globally in Laravel.

Comment: Can be checked by ```request()->method === 'PUT'``` as well.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Request::getMethod()` to get method used for current request, but this should be rarely be needed as Laravel would call right method of your controller, depending on request type (i.e. `getFoo()` for GET and `postFoo()` for POST).

Comment: Isn't that Laravel 3 for `is_post` and `is_get` as Laravel 4 uses camelCase?

Comment: Using separate methods for GET and POST may not be desirable. For simple CRUD use cases, using the same method for both GET or POST can reduce code duplication and lower the mental load of development.

Answer (score 6):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is used for that.

It returns one of the following:

- 'GET'
- 'HEAD'
- 'POST'
- 'PUT'

Answer (score 6):

Of course there is a method to find out the type of the request, [But](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1517) instead you should define a **route** that handles `POST` requests, thus you don't need a conditional statement.

*routes.php*

```
Route::post('url', YourController@yourPostMethod);
```

inside you controller/action

```
if(Auth::attempt(Input::get('data')))
{
   return Redirect::intended();
}
//You don't need else since you return.
Session::flash('error_message','');
```

The same goes for `GET` request.

```
Route::get('url', YourController@yourGetMethod);
```

Comment: Tom's solution below (not picked) is better

Comment: @Krynble You downvoted my answer because it is wrong or because it's not the best?

Comment: Just because I believe it didnt answer the question; you have a point in what you say but for very simple tasks (and when adding server side validation) I believe it's better to handle in a single controller method.

Comment: @Krynble How do you reach your single controller method `Route::any()`?

Comment: Yes, I use Route::any() and handle everything in the controller method; including validation and displaying typed form information back, when needed.

Comment: I agree with @Krynble. This doesn't answer the question. There are circumstances where your POST and GET routes might do very very similar things. This solution encourages unnecessary code-duplication which potentially increases support maintenance in the long run. The number of up-votes on Tom's answer suggests others recognise this too.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse I don't agree with your arguments. In which circumstances POST and GET do similar things ? What about REST, CRUD operations, POST-REDIRECT-GET.  Isn't placing all your code in one method with difference logical paths encourage code-duplication ? What accepted as an answer suggests ?

Comment: @giannischristofakis You're free not to agree :-) But I'm still holding my position. Why would the Laravel framework allow you to send POST + GET down the same route if there wasn't a practical purpose?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326030/how-to-route-get-and-post-for-same-pattern-in-laravel#23235478.

Comment: @Krynble do you need validation in your GET request ? And then when you have an error in your submitted form (I presume it's a POST request) , do you redirect it to the same origin route ?

Comment: @giannischristofakis Practical purposes include: viewing a record in a database, but if the user arrives at that screen via a form (rather than a link), he should receive a "job-done" message. Otherwise the GET/POST routes do exactly the same thing.  It would be code duplication to have to write 2 routes in this circumstance, and "the same screen" might end up doing "different things" as the developer (and future developers) change the code over time. "Accepted answer" means "it was good enough for the asker's needs at the time". It doesn't necessarily mean the actual question was answered ;-)

Comment: @cartbeforehorse You can misuse a framework in all kind of different ways, that's what my answer oppose. I lost you in your explanation. How "the user arrives at that screen via a form" ? You guess, the majority of the voters was looking for Tom's solution, but I guess not the OP.

Comment: You have this situation when using pagination. By default the next page will use the same route the view was called from, so reading a database and paginating the results would would send a get to a method that may also receive a post such as in a search request with parameters. To avoid this you would have to redirect the get request to another method which would do the same database query so duplicating code!

Comment: @Lee I get what you are say, but there is no duplication unless you choose to implement it this way.Your situation is exceptional cause you use a custom query (for your pagination) and a form that posts the query parameters. The redirection as you said is inevitable but you can avoid to do the database query in you post method (which is redundunt and kind of contradictive cause usually POST method stores data and  GET fetches). Just redirect and pass the parameters from the POST to your GET method. I don't get why you downvote an answer that doesn't meet your preferences but still isn't wrong!