# Creating the Post-Redirect-Get pattern with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, post-redirect-get

I have been used laravel, and I find it's by far the best PHP Framework there is. But even so, I still think that to be able to understand it and PHP MVC's in general, I need to make my own first.

So, as of now, I'm in the process of making my own MVC, I got most things covered. But I wanted to add a feature that is identical to Laravel, which is the Post-Redirect-Get feature, (or so I think).

What I mean is, for those unaware, that if a person visits a link, say `localhost/project/laravel/public/profile` using the `Route::get('localhost/project/laravel/public/profile', 'SomeController@action)` He will only be able to view the profile page, from the `action()` function in `SomeController`. But when he uses the `Route::post('localhost/project/laravel/public/profile', 'SomeController@action2)`, only when does is the POST request sent from the `localhost/project/laravel/public/profile URL`, will the `action2()` function activate.

So, My question is,

How can I make my own `Route::get()` and `Route::post()` to work like in laravel

Comment: Laravel has the same relation to MVC as Democratic People's Republic of Korea has to democracy.

Comment: What?, How is what you are saying related? I still dont get it

Answer (score 0):

If you want have `get` and `post` in the same route you should try this methods
[POST and  GET  in the same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326030/how-to-route-get-and-post-for-same-pattern-in-laravel)

Comment: I am not using the Laravel, but I am making my own MVC Framework for which I want it to resemble laravel in the Post and get functionalities through the route class