# Laravel Duplicate Route names

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm using same route name for the **get** & **post** methods in route. those routes are using for the same purpose.
ex : I'm calling to load add view form using **get** route

`Route::get('add', 'UserController@addView')->name('user.add');`
then,

I'm calling to store  data in that form using **post** route

`Route::post('add', 'UserController@store')->name('user.add');`

is there any issue , If I use the same route name like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to route GET and POST for same pattern in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326030/how-to-route-get-and-post-for-same-pattern-in-laravel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not use the same name for 2 different routes as is stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) if you really need to name the routes you should look for different names, but if there's no need to have named routes you can have each url with its method like:

```
Route::get('/your-url', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@addView');
Route::post('/your-url', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store');
```

If you are making a CRUD you can have:

```
Route::resource('user', UserController::class);
```

This will create all the urls needed for a CRUD:

[image]

Comment: But ,If I'm not using the same route name for 2 ```get``` methods. one is for the ```post``` other is for the ```get```.it doesn't return any errors. is there a technical issue?

Comment: I'm not having any error.If this is technically wrong, what is the reason ?

Comment: @Thisaru maybe you are not using the naming? As Abdullah Shakir commented in its response to the same question, if you try to use the route by its name that should lead to an error or an undesired behaviour. Still, is a bad practice and I would suggest you to follow the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get issues in future. For example, I had issues after functionality update - I've updated route interface (added some fields) and new fields does not appeared in result after opening URL.
Please run command `php artisan optimize` to see is it all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have same name for both routes i.e., `name('user.add')`. Change that.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I'm asking is it a technically wrong..? if it is wrong what is the reason.?

Comment: Route names should always be unique. Try to redirect `return redirect()->route('user.add');` and see what happens